# How can show list string via html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDkUA.png]

I have uib-popover in html when I hover, it'll show as image.

Backend I got list FullName, but when I call it on html. It shows as array.
I want to it just show External 1, Dao Thi Hong Nhung, instead of ["External 1","Dao Thi Hong Nhung"].

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var response = ["External 1", "Dao Thi Hong Nhung"];
        console.log(response.join(", "));
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to AngularJS at all. This is a plain JavaScript problem. Assuming that the array name is `testArray`, you can do it as follows:

```
testArray.join(", ")
```

This will produce a string with all elements of the array concatenated by `,`.